# Swift 3 UserDefaults not saving

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Totally stumped on why the below code isn't saving correctly.  I have gone through and printed each variable individually to make sure they all have data and all the way to `latestBottle` everything is fine.  But when I try to pull the value back from UserDefaults, it's `0.0`.

```
func saveBottleEntry() {
    let allBottleEntries = realm.objects(SubmittedEntry.self).filter("bottleQuantity > 0")
    for bottle in allBottleEntries {
        bottleTimes.append(bottle.submissionTime!)
    }
    latestBottle = bottleTimes.max()!
    UserDefaults.standard.set(latestBottle, forKey: "latestBottle")
    print(UserDefaults.standard.double(forKey: "latestBottle"))
}
```

`bottleTimes` is an array of dates being retrieved from a Realm database.  I then take the newest date `bottleTimes.max()` and save that to `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Userdefaults doesn't save immediately but to force it you need to use `UserDefaults.standard.syncronize()` after setting

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Is the `print` statement in the code you've posted so far showing the proper value? If so, then update your question with details about the code that isn't working.

Comment: @Masiama, no change when adding that.

Comment: @rmaddy, the `print` is for me to verify if it saved or not.  Always returns `0.0`

Comment: @FasterThanLlamas if you see 0.0 when try to get double that means that you wrote wrong type

Comment: Show the declaration for `bottleTimes` and `latestBottle`. And what's the value of `latestBottle`?

Comment: @FasterThanLlamas what is the type of `latestBottle`?

Comment: @masiama great catch.  Changed to `UserDefaults.standard.object` and it worked perfectly.  Thanks all!

Comment: @masiama If you'd like to post an answer, I'm happy to mark it.

Comment: @FasterThanLlamas It really would help if you post the request details.

Comment: If `latestBottle` is a `Date`, why do you try to read it back as a `Double` instead of as a `Date`?

Answer (score 1):

If you see `0.0` when try to get double that means that you wrote wrong type to `UserDefaults`

Comment: Or it means that a value of 0.0 was stored. This is not sufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy but as I understood it wasn't that was stored

Comment: If the OP would respond to the comments and post more details about the data types involved, a more thorough answer and solution can be posted. But as a general statement, reading a value of 0.0 doesn't guarantee that the wrong type was written. It's certainly likely in this case though.

Comment: it was just my guess and it turned out to be correct

Comment: Now that we know the OP was writing a `Date` and trying to read a `Double`, a more complete answer can be posted.

Comment: Well, it's up to you.